# Performance across folds in random forest

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, r-caret, roc

I'm trying to get sensitivity, specificity, ppv, and npv (or a confusion matrix can also work) across all of my folds when I train a random forest using `caret`, but specifically if I change the threshold. I know normally with the default threshold you can use `model$resample` to give you the metrics for all of the folds but how do I do this at a new threshold?

Here is my model:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                 number = 5,
                 savePredictions = TRUE,
                 summaryFunction = TwoClassSummary,
                 classProbs = TRUE)

model <- train(outcome ~ ., data=df, 
  trControl = ctrl, method= "rf", preProc=c("center","scale"), metric="ROC",importance=TRUE)
```

Here is how to generate a confusion matrix at a new threshold:

```
 label <- ifelse(model$pred$affirmatory > 0.75, 'affirmatory', 'negatory')
 confusionMatrix(label, model$pred$obs, positive = 'affirmatory')
```

But this only gives me the average values across all the folds. How do I see the metrics for all folds?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my question and wanted to post it in case it benefits anyone in the future.

Here's a reproducible example using `iris`. Say you're interested in the performance in each fold where the `threshold=0.2`.

```
set.seed(3949)
attach(iris)
#create a binary outcome on Sepal.Length
iris <- iris %>% mutate(Sepal.Length=ifelse(Sepal.Length>5.0,"aff","neg")) 


practice <- train(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris, trControl = ctrl, method= 
"rf", preProc=c("center","scale"), metric="ROC",importance=TRUE, tuneGrid = 
data.frame(mtry = 2)) #must specify a single mtry

#examine outcome at every fold
print(practice$pred)
```

You can see that the default threshold is 0.5. If `threshold>0.5`, then `pred` will be `aff` and vice versa. If I want `threshold=0.2`, then I will get `aff` when `threshold>0.2`. So now you just need to create a new column with a new prediction based off of that threshold and then you can generate a confusion matrix from that.

```
f1 <- practice$pred %>% filter(Resample=="Fold1")
f1 <- f1 %>% mutate(new_pred=ifelse(aff>0.2,"positive","negative"))
f1 %>% group_by(obs, new_pred) %>% summarize(n=n())
```

Repeat the above for each of the folds. The last line gives you a broken down confusion matrix. Using that, you can manually figure out sen/spec/ppv/npv. If you want to confirm if this method actually works, you can generate the confusion matrix for the entire model evaluated at a new threshold using:

```
label <- ifelse(practice$pred$aff > 0.2, 'aff', 'neg')
confusionMatrix(label, practice$pred$obs, positive = 'aff')
```

Count the individual combinations in each fold and it will add up to the total in the above confusion matrix. Also if you take any performance metric, say specificity, across each folds and average it, you'll also get the specificity from the above line. Just another check to make sure you're doing everything right if you needed confirmation.